# Is there any application by Microsoft targeting the end user market and running on the .NET framework?

Tags: .net

It's all in the title.
Inspired by http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/dx8au/lessons_from_evernotes_flight_from_net/

Edit: I am primarily thinking about desktop apps, not web apps.

Comment: This seems like a question designed to take a pot shot at Microsoft when read in the context of the article you linked to.  The question itself implies that the asker doesn't believe that Microsoft uses its own product, implying it's no good.  Am I reading this right?

Comment: Certainly not! Actually I am fond of both of the .net framework and C#. But beeing myself not a connaisseur of the MS application ecosystem I wonder if the situation has much changed since 2005 when I quit programming. Actually I thought that MS Office 2003 MUST be written in a way to target the C# plattform given the marketing that was put into back that time. After it was released 2003 I was in disbelieve that this wasn't true.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you'll hardly find mainstream apps from Microsoft written in .NET, since most of their popular applications were built before .NET was released, re-writing them for .NET provides no benefit for them.

But if you look at recent applications you might find .NET based ones:

- Business Contact Manager (mentioned by Martin)
- SQL Management Studio
- Windows Live Essentials
- Power Shell (and Exchange + all other management shells based on PS)
- MMC in Windows (Vista,7,2008)

I know that some are not consumer based, but it shows that recent investments were made on .NET

Comment: I had a similar answer typed out. +1.

Comment: In other words, "Not the one's your thinking about, but not because they don't have confidence in the product, (as a reader might gather from the question)."

Comment: Why not? Windows Live Essentials is end-user and requires .NET

Answer (score 8):

All of Microsoft's websites run ASP.Net.

[Expression Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Studio), parts of which target end-users, is built in .Net and has a WPF-based UI.

Comment: Well put, that counts certainly. I had desktop apps in mind though.

Comment: I'm sure he means client applications (i.e. Applications that depend on the .NET Framework to be installed on the end-users machine)

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio's 2010 GUI is written using WPF. The application is not completely managed though.

Comment: That doesn't target end-users.

Comment: I'm an end user and I use VS2010....  As developers, we are end users of the development IDE, just as someone typing up a document is the end user of Word...

Comment: VS perfectly targets the end users =)

Comment: Agreed, David. Saying that developers aren't end-users of the systems that we are using is too-restrictive. If I am not developing the Visual Studio product itself, I am an end-user of it.

Comment: @SLaks: You really screwed up with that comment. Doesn't do justice to your 86k points... Had OP said "consumer market" then you might have a point, and a partial one at that.

Comment: @gmagana: I'm pretty sure that that's what he meant, even if he used the wrong term.  What do you think he means?

Comment: @SLaks: I think he means what he says: Applications for end users to use.  This is a good definition I found on the web: "The end user is the individual who uses the product after it has been fully developed and marketed."

Comment: @gmagana: As opposed to what?

Comment: @SLaks: Hmm.. Everything else?  Sample programs for developers to kick around, internal stuff never seen outside MS (ie, MS' internal version control system), etc. I think the point is that programmers are end users too.  Blah! This is too philioposhical without my noon shot of tequila...

Answer (score 6):

Most of Microsoft Dynamics are written (or have significant porttions written) in .NET

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_GP

Answer (score 4):

Business Contact Manager

Answer (score 4):

[Windows Live Writer](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-writer) is one - at least the last two versions (and IIRC, all versions since it was first released) are ground-up WinForms.

Answer (score 4):

[Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/)

Comment: Not made by Microsoft, but it is a good consumer market .NET app.